# Visual Studio Code, Python, Alterations Not Running

Tags: python, module

I am trying to alter some code I have been given for my dissertation. However, any alterations to the modules (print statements, logging, and even trying to deliberately break the code with breaks) do not seem to affect the main program running as if those changes were not there, but changes to the main program does affect the output.

All the changes are saved and I have tried reimporting all the data files I am using and deleting all of the results before rerunning to try and start the program from "fresh". But no luck in fixing the issue.

Is there any fix to this problem? Apologies if it is an easy one, still starting out.

Main Program

```
eda = EDA()
cdr3_lengths = eda.get_length_of_repertoires(
    repertoires=repertoires,
    cdr3_col_name="aaSeqCDR3",
    freq_col="cloneCount",
    groups={
            "01.TC8.14": "14days",
            "02.TC4.14": "14days",
            "03.SC8.14": "14days",
            "04.SC4.14": "14days",
            "05.TC8.21": "21days",
            "06.TC4.21": "21days",
            "07.SC8.21": "21days",
            "08.SC4.21": "21days",
    },
)
```

Module

```
class EDA:

# --init method etc --

    def get_length_of_repertoires(
    self,
    repertoires: List,
    groups: dict,
    cdr3_col_name: str,
    freq_col: str,
    save_df: bool = False):

    print("This isn't working")
    cdr3_lengths = {}
    self.logger.info("For loop fetching each repertorie.")
        for repertoire in repertoires: #Repeat seqs len for count
            self.logger.debug(repertoire)
    .....
    return 'value'
```

I have added some of the code that I am working with here, I believe it is being executed. I hope this helps a little more.

Comment: The fix would be to identify which source files are actually executed and then change those. It appears that you are changing other code that is not executed.

Comment: it seems you change wrong files. If you `import module` then check `print( module.__file__ )` to get full path to file with code.

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for your replies! Does the code I have added help give you a little more info!